# QGIS: How to create attribute following polygons' by object-to-object relationships?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to map the sub-basins within North America's Great Basin.  I'm using the [National Hydrography Dataset](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/national-hydrography), 12-digit [watershed boundary](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/national-hydrography/watershed-boundary-dataset) data.  Each polygon has an ID, also either the ID of the downstream polygon, or a code denoting it a terminal basin.

In QGIS, how do I create an attribute populated by the ID of the eventual terminal polygon of each polygon?

For example, consider the following attribute table.  The `ID` and `TO_ID` attributes exist; I want to generate the `TERMINAL_ID` attribute.  The value `T` designates a terminal polygon.

| ID (exists) | TO_ID (exists) | TERMINAL_ID (generate) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | T | 5 |
| 6 | 8 | 8 |
| 7 | 8 | 8 |
| 8 | T | 8 |
| 9 | T | 9 |

Comment: Which table has the downstream polygon IDs?

Comment: @wingnut the same all polygon IDs are in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer and a recursive query.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. Replace `myLayer` with your layer name. It will return a copy of all features in the original layer (with all attributes) and the computed `terminal_id`

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE findTerminal(id,to_id, src_id) AS (
  SELECT id, to_id, id as src_id
  FROM myLayer a --starting point, get all features
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  a2.id, a2.to_id, src_id
   FROM myLayer a2
   inner join findTerminal on a2.id = findTerminal.to_id --until none is found, find the corresponding to_id, but keep a copy of the starting point id!
)
SELECT a.*, t.id as Terminal_ID
FROM findTerminal t
 JOIN myLayer a
  ON a.id = t.src_id AND t.to_id == 'T';
```